# C++ prevent floating point registers from being zeroed in page fault handler

Tags: c++, page-fault

I am writing a program that requires the floating point registers ([xy]mm0-15) to not be overwritten after a page fault.  I wrote the following example code that generates a page fault and then catches it:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void handle(int, siginfo_t*, void* vcontext);

// Page fault handler.  When this is called the fp registers are all zeroed
void handle(int, siginfo_t*, void* vcontext) {
  cout << "Get fp reg here";
  exit(0);
}

main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // Setup sigaction handler for page fault
  struct sigaction act;
  act.sa_sigaction = handle;
  sigaction(SIGSEGV, &act, 0); 

  // Generate page fault
  int i = 10;
  int* iPtr = &i;
  iPtr += 10000;
  cout << *iPtr; // This line will generate a page fault, then sigaction will redirect the program to `handle`.
}
```

I then put the program into GDB and step through it one instruction at a time.  What I find is that in between `cout << *iPtr;` and `cout << "Get fp reg here";`(in `handle()`)all of the fp register values are set to zero.  What I need is for the register values to be preserved so I can use them in `handle()`

As a side note I am using Red Hat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FP registers (and the entire pre-AVX CPU state) is available via the third parameter to `handle` in a `ucontext_t` structure.  See documentation for [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) and [sigreturn(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigreturn.2.html) functions.  However, the YMM registers are not explicitly included in that.

The fpstate stored in [`ucontext_t`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86/sys/ucontext.h.html) comes from the CPU's `FXSAVE` instruction.  This includes the XMM registers (which are also the bottom half of the YMM registers).  The full CPU state is saved with the `XSAVE` instruction or one of its variants.  When appropriate CPU feature sets are enabled, the extended state saved by `XSAVE` will include the top half of the YMM registers in the extra data.

The high half of the YMM registers will be stored at offset given by the CPUID instruction (EAX = 0Dh, ECX = 2) in the EBX register (currently this is 576).  The length of the YMM data is in the EAX register after that CPUID (currently this is 128).

To determine the individual YMM register values, you'll need to glue the two halves together.

There is a [PDF](http://events17.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/LinuxCon_NA_2014.pdf) version of a slide deck that gives an overview of this whole process.

Comment: @TylerH I've done more checking into the CPU instructions to manage the FPU state.  The ucontext data is listed as coming from the `FXSAVE` instruction.  The later `XSAVE` instruction saves the YMM registers (and other state) but in a compact form (the first 512 bytes match the FXSAVE format).  This data _might_ be present in memory but not documented in the structure, since that is the easiest way to save that data during the page fault handling.  I'm going to look into this a bit more.

Comment: @TylerH I've added more details after further investigation

Comment: That worked, thanks. It's a pain finding all that stuff since the header files aren't updated, but it's in memory and can be retrieved